# showing unusual url persian when copy or share

Tags: android, google-chrome, url, firefox, mobile

Android web browser, url of the Persian normally just show. But when I copy or share. url will be displayed as a percentage. I tested on different mobile phones. In some mobile phones, the normal display. And some will be displayed as a percentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such behavior is normal. It is called **URL Encoding** ([sample](http://www.w3.org/International/O-URL-code.html)).
Nowadays URLs can be shown UTF-8 encoding characters in many web browsers. However, for backward compatibility purpose, those characters other than ASCII (US 7bit characters) are encoded with this method intentionally.